# Backscatter relay from Postfix backup mx server causing spam (553 5.7.1)

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam

I have 2 Postfix Servers

- MAIN.mail.example.com
- BACKUP.mail.example.com

**Problem scenario**:

1. If spammer sends email from "me" to me directly to BACKUP, server forwards it to MAIN
2. MAIN server reject email with e-mail send to me `reject mail said: 553 5.7.1 <me@example.com>: Sender address rejected: not logged in (in replyto
   RCPT TO command)`

**How to avoid this Backscatter? What rule and where I can put on BACKUP or MAIN to avaid this false messages?**

Message RAW

```
Return-Path: <>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28) on MAIN.mail.example.com
X-Spam-Level: *
X-Spam-Status: No, score=1.8 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_50,RDNS_DYNAMIC,
SPF_HELO_PASS,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.1
X-Original-To: me@example.com
Delivered-To: marek.studionm.pl@MAIN.mail.example.com
Received: from BACKUP.mail.example.com (IP.eu [IP])
by MAIN.mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 1A62C1800A9
for <me@example.com>; Fri, 12 Oct 2018 16:30:15 +0200 (CEST)
Received: by BACKUP.mail.example.com (Postfix)
id C4DF37D059; Fri, 12 Oct 2018 16:30:14 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Fri, 12 Oct 2018 16:30:14 +0200 (CEST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@BACKUP.mail.example.com (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: me@example.com
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
boundary="13C687D03F.1539354614/BACKUP.mail.example.com"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <20181012143014.C4DF37D059@BACKUP.mail.example.com>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--13C687D03F.1539354614/BACKUP.mail.example.com
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is the mail system at host BACKUP.mail.example.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

The mail system

<me@example.com>: host MAIN.mail.example.com[IP] said: 553 5.7.1
<me@example.com>: Sender address rejected: not logged in (in reply to
RCPT TO command)

--13C687D03F.1539354614/BACKUP.mail.example.com
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Reporting-MTA: dns; BACKUP.mail.example.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 13C687D03F
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; me@example.com
Arrival-Date: Fri, 12 Oct 2018 16:30:13 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; me@example.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;me@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; MAIN.mail.example.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 553 5.7.1 <me@example.com>: Sender address rejected:
not logged in

--13C687D03F.1539354614/BACKUP.mail.example.com
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Return-Path: <me@example.com>
Received: from tools.wormly.com (tools.wormly.com [96.126.113.160])
by BACKUP.mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 13C687D03F
for <me@example.com>; Fri, 12 Oct 2018 16:30:13 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:30:12 +0000
To: me@example.com
From: Wormly SMTP Test <me@example.com>
Subject: Wormly SMTP Test Message
Message-ID: <e1cfc6e8117b33f2f3266c2aa753428c@blog.wormly.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

This message was sent using the Wormly SMTP testing tool by this user:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15



--13C687D03F.1539354614/BACKUP.mail.example.com--
```

BACKUP.mail.example.com

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination
```

Comment: Do you need a backup MX at all? Most sites really do not. Aside from that, you should configure the backup MX to reject any mail "from" your domain, that doesn't originate from your network/users.